# GetTime doesn't correctly display zero's

Tags: java, time, timestamp

I use TimeStamps in my system. Everything works correctly, however I find it annoying to have [12:2:2] as TimeStamp. Because you don't know if it's 20 or 2.

I am tired and sick, and starting to think it is the compiler.

```
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
    Timestamp time = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    super.print("[" + time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes() + ":" + time.getSeconds() + "] ");re
```

How do you guys get correct TimeStamps with the zero's?

Comment: By the way, how can't you tell apart 2 and 20?

Comment: Wow, I gave a bad example. Never mind. It is just annoying to read you know.

Comment: I agree on that it's annoying to read (a bit of OCD, y'know), but `:` in between values still make a distinguishable separation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) or [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
df.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use simple `String.format` with `%2d` flag, i.e. decimal number with at least 2 digits.

```
String.format("[%2d:%2d:%2d] ", time.getHours(), time.getMinutes(), time.getSeconds())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DateTimeFormatter` like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dateTime = format.parseDateTime(s);
```

where s is your datatime string.